# Turn on/off foreign key check for ALL tables in DB2

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, db2

I need a SQL statement which turns off/on foreign key checks in a DB2 database.

All I found so far is this: `SET INTEGRITY FOR <your_table> OFF` but that turns off the constraints only for one specific table. I could iterate through all tables in schema and call that command but that's not very effective. Is this even posible in DB2?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a dynamic query for all your tables

```
db2 "select 'set integrity for ' || TRIM(TABSCHEMA) || '.' || TRIM(TABNAME) || ' off;' 
  from syscat.tables
  where tabschema not like 'SYS%'
  and type = 'T'" | db2 +p -t
```

Comment: Thanks. What worked for me :
`db2 -m -x "select 'set integrity for ' || TRIM(TABSCHEMA) || '.' || TRIM(TABNAME) || ' off;' from syscat.tables where tabschema not like 'SYS%' and type = 'T'" | sed 's/[[:blank:]]*$//' | db2 +p -v`

* The first `db2` command doesn't output the number of rows
* Had to remove whitespaces at the end of each generated query

Comment: How do you return it back on? The OFF works fine on its own but ON triggers an exception. The documentation is about as clear as concrete.

Comment: Never mind, this is some command line voodoo and not SQL